# Which algorithm is suitable for fast search of a message in a range?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

There is a time range (in milliseconds) and each range is associated with a message
The task is to display the corresponding message when we are within the specified time range in a video
In other words, implement subtitle-like functionality
If I were to query this array every second, I would have to perform a find operation on the entire array every second
Is there a faster algorithm? If there are around 50,000 of such ranges, the speed will significantly decrease
Please suggest an alternative algorithm.

```
[
{ start: 1000, end: 2000, message: 'testy' },

{ start: 4000, end: 5000, message: 'test1' },

{ start: 170000, end: 175000, message: 'testf' },

{ start: 180000, end: 185000, message: 'testf' },
]
```

Called "array.find" every second, but it's long.

Comment: Sort this array and do binary search for every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array seems to be sorted in ascending time order. (If it isn't, sort it so it is.) Since arrays offer constant-time access (the value of the index doesn't matter [in any predictable way] for the time it takes to access the element), a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is a good way to zero in on the right time range if you don't know *anything* except the time you're looking for.

If you find that a binary search every time isn't efficient enough, in your case once the video is playing you can use your knowledge of what the last time you needed was and what entry you found for it. For instance, if the last time you had was 172500 and you found index 3, and now you're looking for 177000, you might just scan forward from there for a few elements rather than doing a binary search, then if you don't find it fall back to doing a binary search over the remainder of the array (there's no need to search prior the entry you found if the new time is after the last time). The exact details of how you do that will depend on the characteristics of your data, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible for the Text to overlap, binary search wouldn't be a good idea.
I think you don't need a search algorithm, but a tracking algorithm:

- Sort the Array by start
- Keep track what was the last shown message and what messages a currently shown
- Only check if the next messages have to be shown and if you have to remove some already shown messages.

I created a small example code:

```
let messages = [
  { start: 1000, end: 2000, message: 'testy' },
  { start: 4000, end: 5000, message: 'test1' },
  { start: 170000, end: 175000, message: 'testf' },
  { start: 180000, end: 185000, message: 'testf' },
];
let currentlyShownMessages = [];
let indexOfLastMessage = 0;

messages.sort((a, b) => { return a.start - b.start });

function checkMessages(timestamp) {
  let nextIndex = indexOfLastMessage + 1;
  while (nextIndex < messages.length && messages[nextIndex].start <= timestamp) {
    show(messages[nextIndex]);
    currentlyShownMessages.push(messages[nextIndex]);
    nextIndex++;
  }
  indexOfLastMessage = nextIndex;
  for (let msg of currentlyShownMessages) {
    if (msg.end < timestamp) {
      hide(msg);
      currentlyShownMessages.splice(currentlyShownMessages.indexOf(msg), 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest search algorithm is a binary search on a sorted array having a time complexity of `O(log(n))`.

```js
let messages = [
    { start: 1000, end: 2000, message: 'testy' },
    { start: 4000, end: 5000, message: 'test1' },
    { start: 170000, end: 175000, message: 'testf' },
    { start: 180000, end: 185000, message: 'testf' },
];

messages.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);  // Sort by start time (n log n)

let start = 3000;
let end = 200000;

function searchFirstElement(start) {  // Binary search (log n)
    let left = 0;
    let right = messages.length - 1;
    let result = -1;

    while (left <= right) {
        let mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);

        if (messages[mid].start >= start) {
            result = mid;
            right = mid - 1;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let startIndex = searchFirstElement(start);
let flag = true;
let index = startIndex + 1;
while (flag && index < messages.length) { // O(m)
    if (messages[index].start >= start && messages[index].end <= end) {
        index += 1;
    } else flag = false;
}

console.log(messages.slice(startIndex, index));
```

Total complexity: O(n log n + m)

Comment: btw, it is not log, it is log2 for big o.

Comment: @NinaScholz https://www.google.com/search?q=binary+search+time+complexity

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I kept the search index as message as it is the key that is searched. If we indexed it on the basis of start time, the search will work according to the start time. Anyhow, I think the input of search is message not the start time.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa, for every step you split the search space in half -> log2.

Comment: Then Google uncle is funny @NinaScholz

https://www.scaler.com/topics/time-complexity-of-binary-search/

I hope this helps. Anyhow if you mean that the base is 2, then I accept it. :P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think this solves what you mentioned.

Comment: FWIW, something I noticed in the code: `searchFirstElement` is only checking the element's `start`, it also needs to check against `end`, since otherwise it'll assume any element with a start time >= the target time matches, but that doesn't make sense. Your code returns the 4000-5000 element for the input 3000, for instance. (It shouldn't return any element at all in that particular case, none of the elements matches the time value 3000.)